# A more balanced array manipulation than each_slice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of 10 items and I want to split it up into 3 sections that look like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7]
[8, 9, 10]
```

Using `each_slice` I can get close:

```
a = *(1..10)
a.each_slice(4) # use 4 so I can fit everything into 3 sections

[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
[9, 10]
```

But I want the first format which is more evenly distributed. I can do it writing my own method. <strike>But is there a built in way to do this in ruby 1.9+?</strike>

Update:

Since there's no built in way I'd like to change my question to - **how would you implement it?**

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Slice your `(1..10)` into three almost-even pieces while maintaining the overall order?

Comment: as mentioned, a.each_slice(3)

Comment: Nop, there is no such built in method. Would be curious to see your implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my implementation

```
  def chunk(a, pieces)
     size = a.size / pieces
     extra = a.size % pieces
     chunks = []
     start = 0

     1.upto(pieces) do |i|
       last = (i <= extra) ? size.next : size
       chunks << a.slice(start, last)
       start = chunks.flatten.size
     end

     chunks
   end
```

call it like so

```
a = *(1..10)
puts chunk(a, 3)
```

will output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7]
[8, 9, 10]
```

If piece size is too big it pads with empty arrays

```
a = *(1..10)
puts chunk(a, 14)
```

will output

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [], [], [], []]
```